# Как перехватить действие и считать параметры ?

Tags: delphi

На .exe файл посылается команда с параметрами, как перехватить это действие и считать эти параметры ?

Answer (score 1):

Хотелось бы узнать для начала, как вы посылаете "команду" этому приложению. Многим сразу становится понятно, что речь, возможно, идет о передаче приложению параметров через командную строку( параметры командной строки ), но вы ведь наверняка можете передавать приложению параметры и через реестр и через глобальные атомы, например =)

Если же речь все-таки идет о параметрах командной строки, то получить эти параметры почти в любой момент времени можно чуть легче, чем элементарно **таким вот образом**:

```
...
var str:Pchar;
...
str := GetCommandLine();
ShowMessage(str);
...
```

Comment: есть принтер - нажимаем кнопку сканировать и отправить по почту. Меня не устраивает что он работет с оутлуком и надо руками вводить почту, я хотел бы что бы почта сразу вжииих и улетела. Хочу это автоматизировать, вот думаю подменить экзешний оутлука, перехватить параметры и что то сделать самому.

Comment: @oldzas, рано вы в крэкинг полезли =)

Comment: куда деваться, стоит такая задача. еще дополню, что от принтера перехватывает данные клиентская его программа установленная на компе и потом уже она посылает сигнал оутлуку.

Comment: @oldzas, скажем так, я не копался в хардкоде аутлука, поэтому понятия не имею, какие он там параметры и в какой последовательности получает, поэтому лучше скажите свою абстрактную задачу, не мешая в одну кучу принтер и аутлук =)

Comment: задача проста: по нажатию на турбо кнопку на сканере = от сканированный лист бумаги должен уйти по почте. Трудность заключается в том, что после нажатия на кнопку - сканер посылает данные на комп, клиентское приложение (ПО с дровами) получает и ретранслирует это на оутлук, почему на оутлук - хз, такое ПО.

Comment: @oldzas вы уверены, что идет привязка к exeшнику? Скорее всего отправка идет через MAPI. Вам просто нужно зарегистрировать свою софтину как MAPI клиент и назначить ее дефолтной.

Answer (score 1):

Очень простой вариант реализации:
файл debugger.reg

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\outlook.exe]
"Debugger"="c:\\mydebug.exe"
```

Создаешь приложение mydebug.exe, после скинув в корень диска С:, с таким кодом:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mydebug.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    char *cmdLine = NULL;
    FILE *f;
    cmdLine = GetCommandLineA();                        
    if(cmdLine){
        f = fopen("c:\\out_debugdll.txt", "a+");
        if(f != NULL){
            fwrite(cmdLine, sizeof(char), strlen(cmdLine), f);
                    fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), strlen("\n"), f);
            fclose(f);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

при любом запуске программы, с именем outlook.exe, в качестве отладчика будет вызвано твое приложение mydebug.exe, в результате в файле С:\[out_debugdll.txt](http://out_debugdll.txt) найдешь что-то подобное:

```
c:\mydebug.exe "D:\outlook.exe" /111222
```